# Can a Unity Dash display be made persistent

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

Is it possible to make a Dash display persistent ?. Often it is necessary to look at several of the listed results, when an item is selected the dash disappears and this requires repeating the dash search.

For example the unity-lens-books lens searches for ebooks found in a number of online sources (for me a very useful lens). Often one needs to look at several of the results to find what one is looking for. This requires the search to be repeated for every selected book which is an annoying waste of time.

[Correction - I am wrong, the Book Lens does keep the search results between selections. I became confused over this because because when making a selection from a Dash lens, clicking the Dash icon again takes you to the "home" lens. However, the probem still applies to other lenses.]

Would it not be better to make the Dash result a permanent display rather than an overlay.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible, but it's obviously possible to develop it that way. I would file a feature-request bug on Launchpad.net. One way to accomplish your goal, would be if you had to press the Ubuntu button again to close it. I don't think that would disrupt anything and it shouldn't be too much work. The only issue I can see, is that it would make the Ubuntu button act differently from the other launchers.